# TS Error - Property 'at' does not exist on type 'string[]

Tags: typescript, ide

I dont know if this is a bug or something, but I simply cant remove the TS error in my IDE (Webstorm).

The error appears when I am using `Array.prototype.at()` on any kind of array.

tsconfig.json:

```
"lib": [
        "DOM",
        "ES2020",
        "ESNext"
    ],
```

But this seems not to work, I also added ES2021 - ES2015 but the error keeps on. It does work when I compile it, but I just get the error in the IDE.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

```js
const arr = ["hello", 5, true, {name: "test"}];

console.log(arr.at(0));
console.log(arr.at(1));
console.log(arr.at(-1));
console.log(arr.at(-2));
```

Comment: Which version of TS are you using ? At is available with ES2022 support.

Comment: MatthieuRiegler I use this version: 4.5.4. I dont think ES2022 is supported. Only ES2021 & ESNext are the latest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Array.at` requires `ES2022` target which is available from TS 4.6 onwards.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! Didnt think it has to be ES2022 :)